# Multiple Copies of Elessar Slider on Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, elessar

So I'm adding an Elessar slider (found at https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar) to a website I'm working on. However I wanted to use more than one instance of it. The problem is that if I attempt to add a duplicate of the slider div, or more than two, only the last one will function (the others act like empty containers). I have sifted through similar questions in stack exchange, and so far the question

[jQuery sliders: only last slider working on page with multiple sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062184/jquery-sliders-only-last-slider-working-on-page-with-multiple-sliders)

is the closest to my issue. I've tried to fix my problem by

1) Copying and pasting the function statement for each div with their own unique variable,

2) Inserting the script

```
$( ".slider1" ).clone().appendTo( ".slider1" );
```

to the existing script to clone the same div more than once (a resolution suggestively found in     the link above), and

3) Including the script

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('new').append("<div class='slider1'>"+r+"</div>");
    });
```

in the existing script to append the slider properties to a new div.

But none of these have had luck. The existing html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Elessar Slider</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JS/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="../../elessar/dist/elessar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../elessar/elessar.css">

        <script src="../../elessar/moment/moment.js"></script>

        <script src="stylesheet" src="../../elesser/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../elesser/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../elesser/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

        <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1, h2 {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 60px;
        }

        .elessar-handle {
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        header .pull-right {
            margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
            padding: 9.5px;
        }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!--Div to be copied--!>
        <div style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="slider1" class="container" role="main"></div>
        </div>
        <!----!>

        <script>
            var r = new RangeBar({

                min: moment().startOf('day').format('LLLL'),
                max: moment().endOf('day').format('LLLL'),
                valueFormat: function (ts) {
                    return moment(ts).format('LLLL');
                },
                valueParse: function (date) {
                    return moment(date).valueOf();
                },
                values: [
                [
                  moment().startOf('day').format('LLLL'),
                  moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'hours').format('LLLL')
                ],
                [
                  moment().startOf('day').add(1.5, 'hours').format('LLLL'),
                  moment().startOf('day').add(3.5, 'hours').format('LLLL')
                ],
              ],
                label: function (a) {
                    return moment(a[1]).from(a[0], true);
                },
                snap: 1000 * 60 * 15,
                minSize: 1000 * 60 * 60,
                barClass: 'progress',
                rangeClass: 'bar',
                allowDelete: true,

            });

            $('[role=main]').prepend(r.$el).on('changing', function (ev, ranges) {
                $('pre.changing').html('changing ' + JSON.stringify(ranges, null, 2));
            }).on('change', function (ev, ranges) {
                $('pre.changing').after($('<pre>').html('changed ' + JSON.stringify(ranges, null, 2)));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rest of the slider function is found within elessar.js linked at the top. I'm grateful for any help with this!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to play with?

Comment: All of the code is in this fiddle, including the jquery/bootstrap dependencies and moment.js is included at the bottom:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atstearns23/nehhxsb9/11/        however it doesn't seem to run in fiddle, but runs fine on the computer. I'm sure if you copied them to text files they would run.

Comment: in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/nehhxsb9/13/) fiddle its working properly. check it please

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I didn't think you could redefine role tags. Is there a way to upvote your answer/profile status?

Comment: will make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add different `role` attribute.

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 650px;">
        <div class="slider1" class="container" role="main"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 650px;">
        <div class="slider2" class="container" role="main1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/nehhxsb9/13/)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: the `role` attribute in the demo isn't important, I'm just using it as a selector. When you copy the `div` you end up with two elements with the same `role`, and jQuery selects both. You could use classes instead.